# Failed to Fetch Updates on elemetary OS 5.1 Hera

Tags: release-hera, ppa

Error details:[image: h]

```
: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/cybre/elementaryplus/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
W: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
W: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details
```

Answer (score 1):

That repository was not updated for a very long time. As the error says, there are no packages available for Ubuntu bionic (elementary OS 5.1 is built on it) in that repository:
[image]

One valid way to get those icons is to clone the GitHub repository [elementaryPlus](https://github.com/mank319/elementaryPlus) and use the install.sh script to install it.

Use `sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:cybre/elementaryplus` to remove the obsolete repository.

Comment: In reality what I did to resolve the problem was install "Sofware & Updates" from App Center and then disable all elementaryPlus ppa's.